# Fail with the same heierarchy in one axis and where mdx query

Tags: java, database, mdx, aggregate, hierarchy

I create MDX query:

```
with member [DTime.TimeYearQuaterMonthDayTimestamp].[Times] as
     Aggregate({[DTime.TimeYearQuaterMonthDayTimestamp].[2013].[4].[11].[17],
               [DTime.TimeYearQuaterMonthDayTimestamp].[2013].[4].[11].[18]}
              )
SELECT {[DTime.TimeYearQuaterMonthDayTimestamp].[Year].[Month} ON 1,
       {Measures.Price} ON 0
  FROM [Sales]
 WHERE ([DEndAuction].[true],[DTime.TimeYearQuaterMonthDayTimestamp].[Times] )
```

But in exercise is throw exception:

> Caused by: mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Hierarchy '[DTime.TimeYearQuaterMonthDayTimestamp]' appears in more than one independent axis.

Can you help me? How to improve this query that in exercise does not throw exception?

Answer (score 1):

To explain the error message: MDX permits a dimension to be used several times when it is all within the same axis. For example, if you had dimensions called [A] and [B] then this is allowed:

```
SELECT {[A].whatever} ON ROWS, {[B].whatever} ON COLUMNS FROM [mycube]
```

This is not allowed:

```
SELECT {[A].whatever} ON ROWS, {[A].whatever} ON COLUMNS FROM [mycube]
```

The same applies to the `WHERE` clause, which is like another axis. You cannot use your [DTime] dimension on `1` as well as within the `WHERE`.

Some people create a virtual dimension called [DayOfWeek] with 7 members, or [Hour] with 24 members, in order to show a report with months versus days or months versus hours.